# tfs 2017 on site npm build

Tags: node.js, tfs, npm

I am trying to get a npm build of SPA application using the npm build task. I need the task to use the latest Nodejs and NPM, how can I update the binaries of the task? I have installed the Nodejs on the TFS Build machine but the npm task is not using the latest version, it seems there is another version fixed to tfs in some location

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just need to update the Nodejs to the latest version, then the NPM task will call the latest version of Nodejs accordingly.

So, please check if you have installed multiple versions of Nodejs in different directory, If it is, just remove the old one.

And go to your pool settings page: `http://server:8080/tfs/_admin/_AgentPool` and select your agent, verify that if the `Node.exe` and `NPM` are identified as a **system capability** with the correct path set.  If the latest version not existing there, just try to **restart the agent service to sync** it, if still not be identified, you can try to add it manually. Then try it again.

[image]

Comment: @Faizul Hussain Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update?